# Why can't we interpret the meaning of intercept in the sample regression function by putting x=0?

Tags: statistics, regression

In the book Woolridge, this is written,
"The intercept, $\beta_o$, is the predicted value of y when x = 0, although in some cases it will not make sense to set x = 0. In those situations, $\beta_o$ is not, in itself, very interesting."

This is in the context of SRF, where $\beta_o$ "hat" is the estimated intercept.

What are those situations which the author is talking about?

Comment: One example is when the independent variable ($x$) denotes the height of an american citzen and the dependent variable ($y$) denotes the weight of an american citizen. It is obvious that the intercept of the (linear) regression is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, sometimes the true model is essentially linear in a certain region of x-values where data are available, but is not linear once you get substantially away from that region. The intercept helps fit a line where appropriate, but x=0 may be in the nonlinear region. // Often happens in trials of a drug to determine proper dosage. In the therapeutic region response may be a linear function of dose. But it may take a threshold dose before the drug starts to work, and it may be counterproductive to give more than a certain amount. Regr line only useful to predict response inside key region.